# Is it mentioned to not keep the following idol without offerings?

Tags: food, idols, kali

I heard from several people to not keep the idle of maa kali anywhere if we are not providing any offerings. And if we keep the idol then it will harm the surroundings.

Is it true? Does it have any scriptural backup?

If yes, then what type of harm exactly it can do?

Comment: maa kali is ugra so everyday bhog should be offered

Comment: An idol continues to remain a piece of metal/stone/clay etc unless it has been properly consecrated & the divine essence of the deity has been established through the procedure of pranapratistha. Technically there is no harm in keeping such an unconsecrated idol in one's house but exceptions can occur.

Comment: @AnubrataBit I don't think so. Even form and shape do matter afaik.

Answer (score -2):

Mother-Kālī is generally depicted as an Ugra-Rūpa deity, having a fierce and/or subduing form.

Now, although, not explicitly mentioned about Mother Kālī, one may derive a corollary from the Kāmika-Āgama, basis what it says about the idols of Ugra-type of deities.

So, as per the Kāmika-Āgama, let alone installing an ugra-form idol inside a home, such ugra-mūrtis must be installed outside or at the village periphery only.

> (२६. ग्रामादि देवतास्थान विधिः)
>
> > [Chapter
> > 26](https://archive.org/details/kamika-agama-purva-pada-part-1/page/n409/mode/2up?view=theater), Pūrvapād,  Kāmika-Āgama
>
> ईशविष्ण्वोस्तु मूर्तिस्याद् द्विविधा परिकीर्तिता ।
>   उग्रा शान्ता च
> तत्राद्या उग्रकर्मरता मता ॥ २२ ॥
>
> > 22. The divine forms of Śiva and Viṣṇu are of two kinds. They are the subduing forms (ugra mūrti) and the sublime forms (śānta mūrti). Of these two, the subduing forms are much intent on doing fierce activities to control the evil forces.
>
> ---
>
> शान्तकर्मरता शान्ता मूर्तीरौद्री तु बाह्यगा ।
>  शान्ता तु मध्यगा
> प्रोक्ता ग्रामादौ सर्ववास्तनि ॥ २३ ॥
>
> > 23. The benign forms are much intent on doing gentle activities to benefit the devotees. The fierce forms of Viṣṇu and Śiva are to be
> >     installed outside the village or city. Their benign forms are to be
> >     installed in the middle of the village. This rule is applicable to all
> >     types of villages and cities.
>
> ---
>
> करिकामपुरारिस्तु कालारिस्त्वेवमादयः।
>   उग्रास्तु मूर्तयः
> प्रोक्ताश्शेषाश्शन्ता उदाहृताः  ॥ २४ ॥
>
> > 24. The subduing forms of Lord Śiva are Gajānataka , Kāmadahana, Tripurāntaka, Kālāntaka and such others. All other forms of Śiva
> >     are known as benign forms.
>
> ---
>
> विश्वरूपं नृसिंहं च वटशायिनमेव च ।
>   जामदग्न्यं च जानीयात् उग्रं
> वैष्णवविग्रहम् ॥ २५ ॥
>
> > 25. The subduing forms (Ugra-forms) of Viṣṇu who once appeared as reposing on the leaf of a fig tree are Viśvarūpa, Nṛsiṃha, and Paraśurāma.
>
> ---
>
> ग्रामादेर्बाह्यदेशे तु काननादौ प्रकीर्तितः ।
>   रौद्राणां इह देवानां
> स्थापने फलमुच्यते  ॥ २६ ॥
>
> > 26. **The fierce forms** of Śiva and Viṣṇu **are to be installed on the outskirts of the villages and cities. They may be installed in the
> >     forest and other places. The effect of installing the fierce forms is
> >     now told.**
>
> ---
>
> पूर्वे चेत ग्रामनाशं स्यात् वह्नौ दुश्शीलगास्त्रियः।
>   नाशस्तु
> याम्यदेशे तु प्रेतदैत्यादिभिर्भृशः ॥ २७ ॥
>
> > 27. **If it is installed in the east side, destruction of village will occur. If installed in the south-east, the character and activities of
> >     women living in the village will become corrupted. If installed in the
> >     south, much destruction will be brought by the evil groups of pretas
> >     (evil spirits having a hold on corpses) and asuras.**
>
> ---
>
> रोगैस्तु नैर्ऋते नाशं शोकस्स्यावरुणांशके ।
>   दुस्स्थितिं पावने
> विद्यात् राष्ट्रसंस्थां तु सौम्यके ॥ २८ ॥
>
> > 28. **Installation of fierce forms in the south-west direction will result in decay and death by diseases. If installed on the western
> >     side, people will be engrossed in grief. If installed in the
> >     north-west, life-system will be affected by insurmountable
> >     difficulties. If installed in the north, nationwide calamity and
> >     distress will occur.**
>
> ---
>
> सर्वसंपत्तिरैशान्यां पुत्रपौत्रविवर्धनम् ।
>   ग्रामेत्वेवं समाख्यातं
> सर्वत्रान्येषु वा मता ॥ २९ ॥
>
> > 29. Installation of such subduing forms in the north-east direction will yield all sorts of prosperity. It bestows healthy growth and
> >     longevity to the descendants such as sons and grandsons. These points
> >     are to be held in mind while installing the fierce forms in a village.
> >     Same directions are applicable to other places also.
>
> ---
>
> ग्रामेकुड्यन्तरस्थानेष्वष्टदिक्ष्वपि शस्यते। न मध्ये स्थापयेत्
> रुद्रमूर्तिं ग्रामे विशेषतः ॥ ३० ॥ रुद्रमूर्तिस्थिताचेत्तु ग्रामादौ तु
> तदग्रके। शान्मुर्तिप्रतिष्ठां तु कारयेद्देशिकोत्तमः ॥ तटाकं
> कारयेद्वापि तेन शान्तिर्विधीयते । ३१
>
> > - 30 to 31. **Fierce forms may be installed very near the defensive wall built along the village boundary in all the eight directions. Such
> >   frightful forms are not to be installed in the interior of the
> >   village. This rule is to be strictly observed. If a frightful form is
> >   installed even in the recommended locations of villages and other
> >   places, the foremost Priest should install a benign form in front of
> >   that fierce form. Or, a tank may be constructed in front of the
> >   installed frightful form. By doing so, the violent force of that form
> >   gets appeased.**
>
> English Translation by Dr. S.P. Sabharathanam

**Therefore, we may conclude, that one must avoid keeping the "Ugra-form" of deities like Kālī, Nṛsiṃha, Tripurāntaka-Śiva, etc. even within the community halls, let alone keeping such mūrtis in one's personal home.**

There may be some exceptions to that effect like Ramakrishna Paramhamsa, etc., but exceptions don't dictate the generalized rules.